# UMVUE of two normal distributions

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

Let $X_1, . . . , X_n$ be a random sample from $N(µ_X, σ^2_X)$ and let $Y_1, \ldots, Y_n$ be a random sample from $N(\mu_Y , \sigma^2_Y$), where $\mu_X \in \mathbb R$, $\mu_Y \in \mathbb R$, $\sigma^2_X > 0$ and $\sigma^2_Y > 0$. Assume that $X_i$’s and $Y_j$’s are independent.

(1) Find the UMVUE of $\sigma^2_X/\sigma^2_Y$

(2) Find the UMVUE of $\sigma_X/\sigma_Y$

My attempt:

A complete and sufficient statisitc for $(\sigma^2_X, \sigma^2_Y)$ is $(S^2_X, S^2_Y)$. Also since we know that the sample variance is a biased estimator for the variance, does this mean that the UMVUE is just $S^2_X/S^2_Y$? And similarly for $(2)$ just $S_X/S_Y$? Or have I got this completely wrong?

Comment: Calculate $E(S_X^k)$ and $E(S_Y^k)$ where $S_X,S_Y$ are sample variances with divisor $n-1$ (assuming the means are unknown) to find the UMVUE of $\sigma^k_X$ and $\sigma^k_Y$ respectively. Then use the independence of $S_X$ and $S_Y$ to find UMVUE of $\sigma^k_X/\sigma^k_Y$.

Comment: I think they are unknown. The first question asks to find the UMVUE for $\mu_X - \mu_Y$ which is simply $\bar X - \bar Y$. Isn't $E(S^2_X) = \sigma^2_X$ though?

Comment: Yes. That is correct.

Comment: Is this the same for (2)? The umvue is just $S_X / S_Y$?

Comment: No, you have to find $E(S_X)$ or $E(S_Y)$ as I mentioned before.

Comment: Ok so for (1) it is corrected that $S^2_X / S^2_Y$ is the UMVUE but for (2), I need to find for the general case of k you mentioned above? Is that correct?

Comment: Just to confirm, $E(\sigma^2_X / \sigma^2_Y) = S^2_X / S^2_Y$ by independence, right?

Comment: $E(S_X^2/S_Y^2)=E(S_X^2)E(1/S_Y^2)=\cdots$